# Hierarchical Dependencies with Guice

Tags: java, jpa, guice

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for dealing with the following situation:

```java
public class AppModule extends Module {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new JpaPersistModule("myJpaUnit").addFinder(Dao.class));
    bind(MyJpaInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }

  @Provides
  @IndicatesSomeConstantMap
  @Singleton
  Map<String, String> getMappings(Dao dao) {
    ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> builder = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String>();
    // Build map from Dao
    return builder.build();
  }

}
```

I need to inject @IndicatesSomeConstantMap in other classes. It seem the only way that getMappings can get the Dao is if I bind MyJpaInitializer as an EagerSingleton - which feels wrong. What's the preferred way of dealing with these hierarchical dependencies?

EDIT:

Based on the answer from @jeffcrowe I came up with something like:

```java
public class Module1 extends PrivateModule {

  @BindingAnnotation @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) @Retention(RUNTIME)
  public @interface Jpa1{}

  @Singleton
  public static class JpaInitializer1 {
    @Inject
    public JpaInitializer1(@Jpa1 PersistService service) {
      service.start();
    }
  }

  public interface Finder1 {
    @Finder(query="FROM Foo", returnAs = ArrayList.class)
    List<Foo> getAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new JpaPersistModule("firstJpaUnit").addFinder(Finder1.class));
    bind(JpaInitializer1.class);
  }

  @Provides
  @Exposed
  @Jpa1
  PersistService getPersistService(Provider<PersistService> provider) {
    return provider.get();
  }

  @Provides
  @Exposed
  @Jpa1
  Finder1 getFinder(Finder1 finder, JpaInitializer1 init) {
    return finder;
  }

}
```

This handles the the dependency by wrapping it behind the provider and feels cleaner to me than using the eagerSingleton approach. This also hides the JpaModule behind a private module making it useful in a situation where multiple persistence modules are bound. The new problem is that since the Finder is already bound by the JpaPersistModule we have to add the @Jpa1 annotation to every injection of Finder1. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting case. Normally in a scenario like this you could bind the initializer in normal Singleton scope and inject it into the Dao implementation, and this would ensure that it was done before the Dao was used. Due to the way the Jpa persistence modules are set up, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to add this dependency.

As the OP pointed out to me, JpaPersistModule is final, so we can't work around this by subclassing it. We can, however wrap the binder used to install the JpaPersistModule.

First wrap the binder in a proxy with an overridden the bind() method to intercept the EntityManager.class binding. (BinderProxy implements Binder and passes every call to the Binder given in it's constructor. [Source available here](https://gist.github.com/3063073))

```
new BinderProxy(binder()) {
  @Override
  public <T> AnnotatedBindingBuilder<T> bind(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz == EntityManager.class) {
      return (AnnotatedBindingBuilder<T>) super.bind(clazz).annotatedWith(DefaultEntityManager.class);
    } else {
      return super.bind(clazz);
    }
  }
}.install(new JpaPersistModule("myJpaUnit"));
```

Then add a provides method to your module which ensures Jpa init before an EntityManager is used

```
@Provides EntityManager provideEm(MyJpaInitializer init, @DefaultEntityManager EntityManager em){
  return em;
}
```

Comment: Also just noticed the answer added to the question above. Looks good and doesn't require any of my wrapping tomfoolery!